# jquery ui autocomplete wire up event alternative to document ready

Tags: jquery, webforms, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I like the jquery ui autocomplete library and am trying to create a either a custom control or a custom web control in asp.net webforms.

The documentation, https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ code section, shows that wiring the autocomplete event must happen in document ready portion of the javascript.

Is there a different way to wire it outside of the document ready?

Comment: This is a long shot but ASP.NET Ajax has one `pageLoad` method that can be used in case you're facing conflicts between ASP.NET Ajax and jQuery. If its not do you mind exlplaining what the exact problem is?

Comment: I'm simply trying to create either a custom web control and or a custom control which incorporates the jquery ui autocomplete widget. When using master pages the load order complicates this.